# queryRenderedFeatures return empty list [mapbox_maps_flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart, maps, mapbox

im currently developing a map, in Flutter using the official Mapbox SDK (mapbox_maps_flutter) where i am using GeoJson to display points on the map, and cluster them when the user are zooming out. I am facing an issue, when trying get the propperties (Or any data in that matter) for when the user presses the markers/clusters.

I have followed the Examples provided by the Mapbox team ([See here on GitHub](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-flutter/blob/main/example/lib/cluster.dart)) - I have implemented the GeoData as below:

cluster_source.json

```
{
    "type": "geojson",
    "data": {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
          {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
              "image_prop": "light"
            },
            "geometry": {
              "coordinates": [
                12.548788861715025,
                55.69434861124148
              ],
              "type": "Point"
            },
            "id": "cp1"
          },
          {...}
        ]
      },
    "cluster": true,
    "clusterMaxZoom": 14,
    "clusterRadius": 64
  }
```

cluster_layer.json

```
{
    "id": "clusters",
    "type": "circle",
    "source": "markers",
    "filter": [
      "has",
      "point_count"
    ],
    "paint": {
      "circle-color": "#606f8b",
      "circle-radius": 20
    }
  }
```

cluster_count_layer.json

```
{
    "id": "cluster-count",
    "type": "symbol",
    "source": "markers",
    "filter": [
      "has",
      "point_count"
    ],
    "layout": {
      "text-field": "{point_count_abbreviated}",
      "text-color": "#ffffff",
      "text-font": [
        "DIN Offc Pro Medium",
        "Arial Unicode MS Bold"
      ],
      "text-size": 10
    }
  }
```

unclustered_point_layer.json

```
  {
    "id": "unclustered-point",
    "type": "symbol",
    "source": "markers",
    "filter": ["!", ["has", "point_count"]],
    "layout": {
      "icon-image": "cp_marker_dark",
      "icon-size": 1
    }
  }
```

In my code, i have added the GeoJson to stylelayers in this code block, when the onMapCreated callback:

```
_controller.style.styleLayerExists('clusters').then((value) async {
      if (!value) {
        // Loading points
        final ByteData cpMarkerDarkByte = await rootBundle.load('assets/icons/cp_marker_dark.png');
        final Uint8List cpMarkerDarkList = cpMarkerDarkByte.buffer.asUint8List();

        final ByteData cpMarkerLightByte = await rootBundle.load('assets/icons/cp_marker_light.png');
        final Uint8List cpMarkerLightList = cpMarkerLightByte.buffer.asUint8List();

        await _controller.style.addStyleImage(
            'cp_marker_dark', 2, MbxImage(width: 64, height: 80, data: cpMarkerDarkList), false, [], [], null);

        var layer = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/cluster/cluster_layer.json');
        _controller.style.addStyleLayer(layer, null);

        var clusterCountLayer = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/cluster/cluster_count_layer.json');
        _controller.style.addStyleLayer(clusterCountLayer, null);

        var unclusteredPointLayer = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/cluster/unclustered_point_layer.json');
        _controller.style.addStyleLayer(unclusteredPointLayer, null);
      }
    });
```

I have created this function in the onTapListener:

```
Future<void> _onTapListener(ScreenCoordinate coord) async {
    // Get the feature the user has clicked on
    final List<QueriedFeature?> features = await _controller.queryRenderedFeatures(
      RenderedQueryGeometry(value: jsonEncode(coord.encode()), type: Type.SCREEN_COORDINATE),
      RenderedQueryOptions(layerIds: ['clusters'], filter: null),
    );

    print(features);
  }
```

The above function returnes a empty list. But if i remove the `['clusters']` from `RenderedQueryOptions` it returnes the map features that are pressed road, building ex. Am i searching for the correct layerIds? The documatation of the package is not the greatest.